# How to convert a constructor type to 'System.Windows.UIElement' (blockUIContainer)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a class and I want to use the constructor of the class Rtb(),

```
public class Rtb
{
    public RichTextBox newRTB;


    public Rtb()
    {
        newRTB = new RichTextBox();
        newRTB.IsReadOnly = true;
        newRTB.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(newRTB_MouseDoubleClick);
    }

    private void newRTB_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       .....
    }
}
```

In below code, i created an object of Rtb(),but this object can not assigned to newBUC.Child, an error after run: Cannot implicitly convert type 'WpfApplication1.Rtb' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

```
private void menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BlockUIContainer newBUC = new BlockUIContainer();
        newBUC.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 50, 10);
        mainMenu.Document.Blocks.Add(newBUC);
        Rtb newnew = new Rtb();
        newBUC.Child = newnew;            
    }
```

I tried to use to cast it, and use "as", like below, but it did not work. I think probably i need the right type to perform the assignment, how should i do?

```
newBUC.Child = newnew as BlockUIContainer; 
newBUC.Child = (BlockUIContainer) newnew;
```

Comment: Rtb should inherit from `UIElement`

Comment: The question is what are you really trying to do here, and why aren't you doing it in proper XAML as opposed to procedural code. WPF does not work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add **newnew** as a Child, because you class does not inherit from **UIElement**. But what can you do is set Child to underlying RichTextBox called **newRTB** which inherits from UIElement

```
newBUC.Child = newnew.newRTB;
```

Comment: I am new here, no enough reputation, so it is not allowed me to vote up your answer. I aslo tried this way "public class Rtb:RichTextBox", but it only works partly, newnew can be added as child, but "IsReadOnly" and "MouseDoubleClick" do not work, do you know the reason?

Comment: If your class directly inherit from RichTextBox, you can remove newRTB field and in the constructor just set properties `this.IsReadOnly = True` etc.

Comment: I tried, but this way only works partly too. Anyway, newnew.newRTB works 100%

Comment: UNLESS you NEED to work with Rtb class in an abstract way (for example outside of your main app where WPF controls may not be available) your best bet is to either A> Make your Rtb class inherit from RichTextBox or B> have Rtb class internally hold a reference to the actual RichTextBox being used.  (Based on the answer you accepted above it looks like you chose path B which does work.     The main drawback with B is having to pull the "richtextbox" out of your own class to use it as a UIElement instead of just inheriting from RichTextBox to create your own customized RichTextBox class.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing a reference to PresentationFramework.dll 
located on Program files* x86( reference assembles¥Microsoft\FRamewrk\3.0\
or your FRamework version

This got me access to all dependencies on my XAML Partial class and therefore able to resolve

I hope this also can help on your coding, It worked for me.